# Copying files to external HD formatted to ext4

Tags: 14.04, permissions, ext4

I have bought an external HDD, transcend 2TB 2.5 and formatted it from FAT32 to EXT4 since I work most of the time with ubuntu. Now when I want to copy files from my computer to the device I get the message `cannot be copied because you do not have permissions to create it in the destination.`

I tried to change it using the terminal:

```
$cd /media/user/transHD   
$sudo chmod -R -v 777 *
[sudo]password for user: 
mode of ‘lost+found’ retained as 0777 (rwxrwxrwx)
```

But again I get the same message. How can I return myself my lost permissions?

Comment: Did you change the owner+group of that disk/partition? transHD needsa to be changed too probably ;)

Comment: Please show how you mounted this. Did you use `mount`? Or `udisks`? Or was it auto-mounted?

Comment: Formatted it again now using Disks utility and now I got access. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case of external drives formatted in ext4 filesystem, is not convenient to work directly on the partition, but to create a directory such data, and in this work, prior to grant full permissions.

Example:

```
sudo -i
mkdir /media/user/transHD/data
chmod -Rf 777 /media/user/transHD/data
```

Then you should be able to work seamlessly with files and directories in /data